# Why don't Jews sacrifice animals anymore?

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, sin, messiah, korban

Correct me if I'm wrong, but Jews do not currently sacrifice animals like ancestors long ago. Why do Jews not currently sacrifice animals? Will there be a time when sacrificing returns once again? How are sins forgiven if an animal is not sacrificed to cover for those sins?

Comment: Hello android.nick! It may be a mistake to link sacrifices to sins as tightly as you do. There was a relatively small subset of sacrifices whose purpose was to take care of sins. Many were brought for other reasons and many sins were atoned for by other means, even at the time of the Torah. Also, check out this related answer: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/maimonides-and-sacrifices

Comment: Also, no sacrifice (that I can remember) brought "slichot" (forgiveness) for the sin, only Kaprah (atonement)

Comment: @avi, could you please elaborate on that distinction?

Comment: another time, but on Yom Kippur we ask for Slicha and Kaparah.

Comment: Normally, slicha only happens when you do teshuvah. Your are completley forgiven and the sin can never be held against you again.  Kaparah just means you've paid for atonement, however it still counts against you if you do it again.  When you have kaparah one can always say "How many times do I have to tell you...", but with Slicha, such a thing can never be said, since its as if you never did it.

Comment: ugh, I have heard the word Yom Kippur, but don't know what exactly it is, I don't know what teshuvah means or is. So is Kaparah just aaa.. translation of a Hebrew word meaning you've paid for atonement, like you said, or is there more to it? Is slichot a translation for forgiveness, and Kaprah a translation for atonement, or is there more to it? In the sense of, does one of those words represent something more? Like a ceremony or something that happened? Sorry, you're speaking to someone completely ignorant. Maybe I should be using Google?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52/should-we-have-a-jargon-policy-guideline

Comment: This question, and other questions like it from the same poster, seem like missionizing to me. In fact, a missionary posed to me this very question on a bus in Talpiyot many years ago. The point is not to get an answer, but to introduce doubt. (The idea is that since Jews don't have sacrifices, they have Jesus, the paschal lamb, to atone for their sins.) I have a good answer that answers this to the point. However, I am not going to present it, because I don't think we should encourage the transformation of this site into a site for missionary activity.

Comment: @josh The questions in question (including this one) have so far gotten some very high-quality, 100% Jewish answers and have not been followed up by any actual missionizing. Clearly, we won't tolerate actual missionizing here, but do we also need to prohibit suspected precursors to missionizing? If anyone's interested in discussing this, rather than doing it here, please drop into [chat]. It works fine for asynchronous discussion, so even if no one's there when you drop in, feel free to post your thoughts and respond to others.

Comment: @josh ... Here in particular, the "shouldn't you therefore accept Jesus?" punchline was never stated, and some of the comments and answers ably point out misconceptions in the question to the point that such a punchline just wouldn't make sense.

Comment: It was not explicitly stated, presumably because such would not be tolerated. The point is to introduce doubt. And many people who read and ask on this forum are not sufficiently Jewishly educated to appreciate a good answer. (Even my bus-mate, from the same yeshiva, did not know how to respond, and was left confused, just from the question.)

Comment: @josh Don't you think [Shalom's answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8862/why-dont-jews-sacrifice-animals-anymore/8876#8876), which comes up at the top by default, does a great job of alleviating any doubt? If people are going to get this question on the bus from time to time, isn't it good that they might see it here, with a good answer, first?

Comment: @android.nick  Sorry, Yom Kippur is a holiday where we ask that all our sins get Forgiven and Attoned for. (Selicha is the hebrew word for forgivness, Kaparah is the hebrew word for 'atonement'). Atonement and Forgiveness are two separate processes / legal concepts.  Any rituals that are associate with Atonement are unique to the thing being atoned for, and vary based on circumstances.  There is also ritual for forgiveness, but it is less dramatic. (for example a person must first forgive you verbally infront of witnesses)

Comment: @josh I agree these are "missionary questions", however people have to ask them to know the correct answers, or if they find them on the internet, need to know what the true answers are.

Answer (score 20):

[Moses makes it clear](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?action=displayanchor&pentid=P5258) that when the Jews enter the Promised Land, eventually one special place shall be chosen, and that will be the only place that animal sacrifices are authorized. That place is the Temple in Jerusalem.

Today the Temple does not stand; it's unclear exactly where on the Temple Mount area the altar stood; there are numerous uncertainties regarding other prerequisites for sacrifice (such as the required garb for the priests); and let's not even get into today's hot-button political reality in Jerusalem! For these reasons and others, animal sacrifice is not done today. However on Sabbaths and holidays, our prayers clearly say that we hope to be brought back to a rebuilt Temple and offer the required sacrifices once again.

Now as the Prophets made clear time and time again ([I Samuel 15:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt08a15.htm), [Isaiah 1:10-18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1001.htm), and so many others)  -- G-d is interested in sacrifices only so much as they mean following His will. If the people are out there doing all sorts of other horrible things but bringing nice sacrifices, then sacrifices shmacrifices. Here's Isaiah (with slight paraphrasing) just so you get the sense:

> Listen to the word of G-d, you people who have become as corrupt and selfish as those of Sodom: What do I need with all your sacrifices, says G-d; I've had enough with burned rams and the fat of well-fed animals; the blood of cows, sheep, and goats? I don't want it. When you approach My Presence in the Temple, who asked you to do this, trampling all over my yard?! Cease and desist, bringing false gifts; incense has become disgusting to Me. New-months, Sabbaths, designated holidays? I can't deal with the sin at these gatherings. I hate your new-months and holidays, they've become a burden I'm tired of bearing. And when you raise your hands in prayer ... I'm not listening -- your hands are full of [innocent] blood. Instead -- clean yourselves off! Get rid of the wrongdoing! Learn to do good, seek justice, improve the lot of the disenfranchised; give justice to the orphan and pursue the case of the widow. Let's make a deal, says G-d; if your sins were like bright crimson, they can become white as snow.

Hence, sacrifices as part of the worship of G-d help, but Judaism goes on without them. As far as atonement, the Laws of Repentance were described by the Talmud and codified by rabbis long ago. We are obligated to recognize our sins, confess them to G-d, regret them, accept upon ourselves to do better, and make good on that acceptance. If we do that, we've done our part.

Comment: We don't need a Beit Hamikdash to offer sacrifices. We do however, need to know the exact location of the altar. See here: http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/halak67/17halak.htm

Comment: @Menachem, I'm aware of a great deal of nitty-gritty such as your discussion. I chose to gloss over that to answer this question at the level it was asked. כל המוסיף גורע

Answer (score 7):

To answer a few of your questions, since there is no temple since the second was destroyed two millennia ago, there are no sacrifices. There is a concept of the messiah coming, bringing a third temple where, presumably, there would be sacrifices once more.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in other answers, we don't offer sacrifices these days because once the Beit Hamikdash was established as the permanent House of G-d we are no longer allowed to offer Korbanot anywhere else. Although the Rambam holds that we do not need the Temple to be standing in order to offer Korbanot, the Korbanot still must be offerred on the Temple Mount. Other factors however, prevent us from offering Korbanot these days. (see [here](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/halak67/17halak.htm)).

There is a group trying to restart the Pascal Sacrifice, with much opposition (see [here](http://www.korbanpesach.org/en/korban/today.htm)).

Our Sages tell us that these days, prayer was established in place of sacrifices (See [Berachot 26B](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=50&size=1) - in English [here](http://halakhah.com/berakoth/berakoth_26.html)).

Furthermore, our Sages tell us ([Menachot 110A](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=4608&size=1) - page 408 in [this document](http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Menachoth.pdf)) one who learns about a sacrifice is as if he gave that sacrifice. Also, learning Torah in general is considered as giving sacrifices (or prevents the need to bring sacrifices).

From [here](http://judaism.about.com/od/abcsofjudaism/f/sacrifice_replc.htm):

> Prayer has taken the place of sacrifices in Jewish practice. Hosea 14:3 reads, "Take with you words, and turn to the Lord. Say to Him, forgive all iniquity and receive us graciously, so we will offer the words of our lips instead of calves."

And see [here](http://www.jewfaq.org/qorbanot.htm) as well.

And see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korban#Future_of_sacrifices_in_Judaism) for different opinions in Jewish writings about whether and which sacrifices will resume when Moshiach comes and the 3rd Temple is built.

Answer (score 1):

We actually do sacrifice animals in order to eat.

In short, we do not sacrifice animals in worship because there's no place to do it.

Please note that there were many other kinds of korbanot in the temple other than sin-forgiving.
Today, for forgiveness of our sins, we can do teshuva. Also in general Hashem sends us kaparot, like bumping on the coffee table, waiting for the bus, etc. But this depends on which sin. There are those that require death as kapara.

Comment: Why did this get a -1?  The laws of schechta come from the laws of karbanot and is part of Kodshim.

Comment: I like your points, and could upvote you if you clarify your answer more by improving syntax and adding detail.

Comment: @Avraham "We actually do sacrifice animals in order to eat." Is this referencing today? Do you mean, by going to a kosher butcher, "We actually do sacrifice animals in order to eat"?