# Can one bring a Korban nowadays?

Tags: kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, conversion-to-judaism, korban, current-events

Assuming we don't have a problem with the Dome of the rock.

---

Has anyone discussed sacrifices nowadays regarding:

1. Can (and should) one bring sacrifices nowadays as we don't know the exact location for the Altar.
2. Who should be doing the sacrifices, as we don't have true Kohanim Meyuchasim nowadays (all Kohanim are only assumed Kohanim as we have no outside proof of their Kehuna status.
3. A [convert](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=4315) must bring a sacrifice upon converting. Nowadays, we can't bring sacrifices so [they don't have](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=4316) to, and are considered normal Jews until the Beis Hamikdash is built.

   In a situation where we would have full control over the Temple mount, if one is allowed bring a korban, all converts would have to do so. However, if one would not be allowed to bring a korban (either because one doesn't know who is a real kohen, etc.) one would naturally be forbidden to bring a korban.

   Would we then say that all converts would revert back to a doubt?

Comment: In your paragraph 3, it's not just "until the Beis Hamikdash is built." See [Likkutei Sichos 26:160](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14949&pgnum=250)ff, where the Rebbe explains Rambam as saying that anyone who converted before the Beis Hamikdash was rebuilt (or, based on the premise of your question, before the korbanos can be resumed) remains fully Jewish even after that. As he puts it (p. 163 there), "it is impossible to say that something gets taken away from his sanctity because the Beis Hamikdash was built!"

Comment: Who said the convert isn't obligated to bring a korban? Maybe he is Jewish and just has an obligation that he currently can't fulfill. When he will be able to bring it he will still be obligated, but that has nothing to do with his Jewish-ness.

Comment: @Alex Forgot... Either way, then we wouldn't be able to accept new converts at that time.

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer this, but I wanted to make few comments. 1. Because of archelogical digs, we now have a fairly good idea where the Altar and courtyards are. 2. There is a group trying to get permission from the Kenesset to bring pesach offerings which removes certain restrictions regarding kohanim and tumah I believe.  I.e. I believe there are some karbonot which do not require a kohen.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8862/why-dont-jews-sacrifice-animals-anymore

Comment: @avi I don't think there is any korban that doesn't require a kohen. Tumah can be dealt with, but you still need kohanim to offer it!

Comment: @DoubleAA Might be right, but I could have sworn there were sacrifices which are brought by the person directly and not by the kohen.

Comment: @avi I think that for all sacrifices, a non-kohein is allowed to (and in the case of personal sacrifices, the owner is even encouraged) to shecht the animal himself. But everything else is solely done by the kohen. Why don't you ask this as a new question and we can find out for sure?

Comment: @avi (about the archeological digs): do we really now know where the Altar was? I'd be interested in any writeups on this that you can point me to.

Comment: @Alex no not yet.  However they have fully mapped/found the foundation of all the retaining walls, which means it can now be plotted accurately.

Comment: @avi: you mean the retaining walls of the Har Habayis (of which the Kosel is one)? Then that doesn't help much, because we don't know exactly how far it was from each of those walls to the corresponding wall of the azarah. (If you mean that they've mapped the foundations of the walls of the azarah, then I'd still be interested in seeing a writeup of that.)

Comment: No just har Habayit. The azarah will not be able to be seen until the Muslims allow archeologist to dig on the mount proper.  However there are 3 or 4 current theories based on other information, which the proper mapping of the har habyit is able to confirm or reject some of them.  http://www.templemount.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of ink has been spilled on this topic. Kaftor Vaferach (ch. 6) [reports](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47648&pgnum=169) that Rabbeinu Yechiel of Paris (who immigrated to the Land of Israel, with his students, sometime in the 1250s) proposed in 5017 (1257) to go to Jerusalem and offer korbanos, and mentions the concerns about tum'ah (which he goes on to dismiss, since public korbanos override it) and kohanim meyuchasim (which he doesn't address).

Footnote 55 there cites a lot of sources from Acharonim on the pros and cons, including these considerations and many others. There's also a nice writeup on it in [*Contemporary Halakhic Problems*, vol. 1, pp. 244ff](http://books.google.co.cr/books?id=Y4SPB17NkzAC&lpg=PA265&ots=GIEARb0rCz&dq=J.%20David%20Bleich%20korban%20pesach&pg=PA244#v=onepage&q&f=false).