# When was the last Korban Pesach done?

Tags: history, passover, korban

In which year, or decade, was the last Korban Pesach performed by Jews on Har Habayit?

So far, [my research](http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1536/comment-page-1) has found Rabbi Gamliel of Yavneh, and his slave Tevi, which would be around 80-120 CE.  But I wouldn't know where to look for the actual answer.

Comment: Its not clear that they actually did a real one and not a zecher lepesach

Comment: @DoubleAA It's pretty clear.

Comment: @avi you might find this link helpful "Can We Offer the Korban Pesach Without the Beis HaMikdash?" http://rabbikaganoff.com/archives/1536/comment-page-1

Comment: @Eramm Thanks, that was where I got the info about R. Gamliel. But based on other conversations I have heard, I don't think his article is complete.

Comment: See the Netziv / Ha'amek Davar. "Vahashimosi es mikdesheichem, velo ariach bre'ach nichocachem." Destruction of the Temple ruled out any *reiach nichoach* sacrifices, but he says that they continued the Pesach (never uses that phrase) for some time afterwards. Check his language and his sources.

Comment: @avi can you add some sources for the research you mention in your question?

Comment: @Menachem It's just [this Mishna](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%96_%D7%91). Apparently that's considered "pretty clear [evidence]".

Comment: [Gamliel II was appointed Nasi about 10 years after the Churban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamaliel_II). Hence he definitively lived and offered Korbanei Pesach during the Temple time. So no Chiddush.

Comment: The link in @eramm’s comment above is stale; use this instead: http://rabbikaganoff.com/can-we-offer-the-korban-pesach-without-the-beis-hamikdash/

Answer (score 1):

According to [machon mikdash](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150395081714969&set=a.86889944968.20323.22738684968&type=1&theater),  the last korban pesach was done during the reign of empiror Justinian between 482 and 565

see:  http://www.templeinstitute.org/Jews-Worship.pdf

> Rabbi Tzvi Hirsch Chayot (1805, Galicia- 1855, Russia) thought it
> likely that the Pascal sacrifice continued to be  offered as late as
> the reign of Emperor Justinian (482–565).8
>
> 8  Responses nos. 2 and 76, as well as ch.2 of his Darkei Hora'ah

Comment: Do you know that machon hamikdash agrees with R Chayot's analysis?

Comment: If they don't agree, then they shouldn't have made a post about it :D

Comment: ????? You're joking, right? People post interesting opinions all the time even without necessarily agreeing to them.

Comment: Why would I be joking? They host the pdf on their site, and advertised it.  The only reason I know about this, is because they advertised that specific line.

Comment: ...and therefore what? Who says they have any scholarly opinion on the matter? They are just presenting an interesting opinion. This post should read, "According to machon mikdash, Rabbi Tzvi Hirsch Chayot thought it likely that the last korban pesach was done during the reign of empiror Justinian between 482 and 565"

Comment: @DoubleAA Did you click on the link?