# Extraterrestrial Sacrifices

Tags: beis-hamikdash, korban

I have heard that it is forbidden to bring a sacrifice to HaShem anywhere on Earth other than the Bait HaMikdash. But what about space? Other planets, say Mars?

Comment: Where did you hear this?

Comment: I think I have heard it at several times in many places over the years. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8884/2177

Comment: That answer says nothing about Earth specifically.

Comment: Depends on whether mitzvos apply in outer space http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat/23402#23402

Comment: I thought this question was going to be about sacrificing aliens.

Comment: Where do we find the Issur being about Earth? The Issur is outside of the Beis Hamikdash. On the other hand,I guess ירושלים של מעלה is permitted. Doesn't it say that מיכאל המלאך brings Karbanos up there?

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot say for sure without checking it up I believe the halachah is once the beis hamikdish was built one is not allowed to bring a sacrifice anywhere else; on this planet or on another.

Comment: Unfortunately, although you may be right, this answer is less valuable than the question (which is valuable only for entertainment and wild speculation).

Comment: @seth j assuming sciencetific progress continues after moshiach comes it won't be a irrelevant question. Several nations have plans to have a moon colony by 2030 so it would become relevant.

Comment: That wouldn't transform this answer into a higher quality answer, nor the question into a higher quality question. Edits to each would do that.