# Why is Maimonides View of Korbanot not Consistent with Messianic Times

Tags: rambam, messiah, korbanos-ketores-prayers

Maimonides theorized in his "Guide to the Perplexed" that Hashem did not favor *korbanot* (animal sacrifices), but allowed them due to the difficulty changing the nature of people. This is in the context of Israel being captive and accustomed to Egyptian ways. The concept of G-d being "reluctant" suggests He did something with hesitation and doubt. How could G-d be in conflict and doubt? Why would G-d "think" Israel couldn't possibly eradicate their pagan-like origins?

I understand that many rabbinic authorities opposed (and continue to do so) Rambam's view on this matter. How did he reconcile this concept with the restoration of the Third Temple during messianic times and the reintroduction of mandatory daily sacrifices? Today, most westerners, including Jews, see animal sacrifices as backwards, *kapporos* notwithstanding. Hashem didn't foresee this?

Comment: -1 why would you assume the Halacha would change even if the original reason is no longer present?

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=8&hilchos=49&perek=8&halocha=8&hilite=

Comment: @doubleaa. I resent your down vote. This is an excellent question. It was my understanding that it was Maimonides view that G-d did not want animal sacrifices but he "allowed" them very reluctantly. The concept behind "reluctant" suggests something done with hesitation and doubt. How could G-d be in conflict and doubt? Why would G-d "think" Israel couldn't possibly eradicate their pagan-like origins?

Comment: I like the question in your comment so +1 to that. It is not the same as the one in the above post.

Comment: You're right @DoubleAA. My intent was to understand how Maimonides who declared belief in the messiah mandatory to Jewish faith could so easily dismiss korbonot when it will be an integral part of the Third Temple. Does his belief that Hashem reluctantly commanded this suggest that sacrifices will have less significance in Messianic times? The three cardinal sins in Judaism have more negative implications than, say, stealing. Is it possible korbanos will have less intensity?

Comment: @JJLL If you amend your question to ask what your comment asks, I'd bet DoubleAA would reverse his downvote and give you an upvote.

Comment: I don't think there is any question that Rambam davened te same Mussaf prayer that asks for the return of the Temple service.

Comment: Hello Bruce. It is the very idea that Hashem did not intend for Israel to make korbonos but nevertheless did. Rambam's belief that it would be too difficult for Israel to give up a pagan ritual such as animal sacrifices is what stumps me as most westerners have done just that, other than pagans and those Jews who participate in kapporos.

Comment: @BruceJames http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/2700n.htm#38

Comment: Related: "[Maimonides and Sacrifices as G-d's concession to Mankind](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6865/1368)".

Comment: JJLL, wanna remove your second paragraph as duplicated by the question @TamirEvan linked to?

Comment: http://www.rashiyomi.com/rambam.pdf

Comment: @Danno. I didn't get a chance to read the link yet but it looks great.

Comment: this question assumes that a reason given by the rambam is the only reason for having karbanos according to the rambam

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maimonides and Sacrifices as G-d's concession to Mankind](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6865/maimonides-and-sacrifices-as-g-ds-concession-to-mankind)

Comment: Maimonides felt that G-d neither wanted nor needed sacrifices.