# Sources that teach that animal sacrifices will not be required in the times of Moshiach?

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, korban

I remember being told that there are opinions that in the times of Moshiach, animal sacrifices will no longer be required. Where are the sources for this opinion?

Comment: http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/897

Comment: @GershonGold - looks like (the basis of) an answer to me!

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6865/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53224/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44214/759

Comment: It is long and I do not have the time to extract the answer and post. If someone wants to do so, please do.

Comment: *Vayikra Rabba* on *Emor* 27:12: "ר' פינחס ור' לוי ור' יוחנן בש' ר' מנחם דגליא לעתיד לבוא כל הקרבנות בטילין וקרבן תודה אינו בטל לעולם... הה"ד... קול אומרים הודו את ה'... מביאים תודה בית ה' (ירמיהו לג י"א) זה קרבן תודה"

Comment: @Fred, I don't see the relevance. The Korban Todah also includes an animal. Are you saying the Korban exists but the circumstances requiring bringing it won't?

Comment: http://ravkooktorah.org/VAYIKRA58.htm

Comment: @Yishai The relevance is that there are sources indicating that a radical change will eventually limit the type of sacrifices that will be brought, just as there are similar sources about an eventual reduction in the number of holidays that will remain in force. Even then, the obligation to bring the *shalmei todah* (including animals) seems to remain in effect. I don't think most sources agree with R' Kook about the eventual abrogation of all animal sacrifices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's based on a reading of the Rambam. In Moreh Nevuchim the Rambam devotes a large section of his sefer to make all mitzvos intelligible. He ascribes to the mitzvos associated with korbanos the need to give Jews a form of service that is akin to what they were used to in the world. Sort of like weaning them off from Avoda Zara. That being the case, korbanos would be unnecessary in the days of Moshiach (במהרה בימינו).

However, as many have pointed out, this cannot be said in the Rambam. The Rambam himself writes in Mishneh Torah that all Korbanos are chukim, and are beyond our understanding. He has great sections devoted to halachos of korbanos which will be relevant in the third and final Beis HaMikdash. Indeed, the Rambam davened (basically) the same tefillos we daven, and always expressed as we do the desire for the Beis HaMikdash and the opportunity to bring korbanos again.

Moreover, there are many p'sukim in Nach that explicitly tell us that there will be korbanos in the times of Moshiach. Examples: Yeshaya 56:7, Yirmiya 33:17-18, Zecharya 14:21, Yechezkel 43:22-25.

Comment: I already heard from the mouth of Geonim Atsumum, this and it is very interesting but as you are yourself noted the the mishne torah remain with all halachot zvachim. So it is not really a source.

Comment: "It's based on a reading of the Rambam." There may be a way to read that into the Rambam (as you point out it is a bit of a problem ...). However, It is most commonly attributed to Rav Kook, and he uses the Arizal as his basis, although he probably means *eventually*. BTW, the argument that according to the Rambam Moshiach will be an era without the need to wean off of Avoda Zara seems unfounded, based on a view of the Messianic era that is more transformative than the Rambam's view.

Comment: The Rambam (Melachim 11:1) explicitly writes that during *yemos hamashiach* we will continue to sacrifice *karbanos*. המלך המשיח עתיד לעמוד ולהחזיר מלכות דוד ליושנה לממשלה הראשונה ובונה המקדש ומקבץ נדחי ישראל וחוזרין כל המשפטים בימיו כשהיו מקודם מקריבין קרבנות ועושין שמטין ויובלות ככל מצותה האמורה בתורה