# How do we learn "Taamei HaMitzvos"?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

The [Rambam](http://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-fox-on-parsha/parshat_vayikra_2/) famously believed that sacrifices were given to ween people off idolatry.

Therefore, it can be assumed that when Mashiach comes, there won't be a need for sacrifices. Yet, the Rambam doesn't mention that in the Mishnah Torah.

There are many other places where "rationalistic" Taamei Torah (reasons behind Mitzvos) contradict Halacha.

How are these resolved?

Comment: Did you mean `wean`?

Comment: Rav Kook says that the third Beit Hamikdash won't have sacrifices.

Comment: Rambam in end of Hilchos Me'ila seems to say differently than what he famously believed, in a way which would suggest that it won't become obsolete.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37433/4794

Comment: Too broad? Isn't every case different?

Comment: @DoubleAA it depends on the nature of the question; perhaps it should be modified to ask why did the rishonim (Rambam in particular) think that the taamei hamitzvos that they (he) gave don't necessarily fit with the actual halakhic details. The Rambam himself points this out (and gives a sort-of answer)

Comment: @YEZ how does that comment contradict what he says in the Moreh Nevuchim? In Hil. Meilah he doesn't give any actual explanation, he just says that God's commands are worth studying, thinking about, and finding the reasons for them.  The reason might still be that they were made to 'wean' the Jews off of idolatry

Comment: "rationalistic" I'm not sure what you mean by this. Are you contrasting to "Kabbalistic"? If so then I'm confused because plenty of "Kabbalistic" reasons contradict Halacha too.

Comment: @Matt he calls it a Chok

Comment: @DoubleAA At least most of the time they admit that the reasons are either spiritual and can't be taken literally, or not the true, not the true and complete reason, or say that one should follow Kabbalah over the Halacha. I understood that the Rambam held the reasons given are the full and complete reasons for the Mitzvos and didn't like "super rational" explanations. I want to know what he did with the contradictions.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin so what? He thought all the chukim had reasons

Comment: @Matt Rambam says in the same halacha to which I referred that chukim are "אין טעמן ידוע" - the reason is unknown.  So even if they have a reason, we certainly don't know it.

Comment: @YEZ I meant an understandable (to man) reason, as the Rambam gives for all the mitzvos, even the chukim. In Hilchos Meilah, he just meant that their reasons aren't known to everyone (i.e. they may belong to סתרי תורה, the subject of Moreh Nevuchim), but they are known to the Rambam and (later) to readers of the Moreh. He doesn't mean that these are inherently unintelligible to man

Comment: @Matt I never said they were inherently unintelligible.  But the reasons certainly aren't obvious, and I can't imagine the Rambam would have intended based on his conjecture any halachic ramifications. In any case, I am not the first to see these two Rambams as being somewhat contradictory.

Comment: @YEZ I know (R. Yaakov Kamenetsky is another, whose opinion I obviously regard very highly), but one of my Rebbeim who I consider to be in expert in Rambam doesn't see any form of contradiction. But you're definitely right that the Rambam didn't intend for his taamei hamitzvos to have halakhic import, he says that himself (basically). See my first comment above

Comment: We don't know the reasons behind a mitzvah 1000% only gd does. So the Rambam thinks that, ok Tarti Dsasri on him k'nal  but the Torahs havent said or implied like him. Idol will b gone (g'sukkah kyadua). As idol is the worst (G'shabbos Kayduah).

Answer (score 1):

Rambam In Igeret Teman states that every mitzvah has two 'parts' , or, 'aspects' , the one that benefits you (being away of idolatry, or In forbidden meals there is a health benefit to your body ) , and the part that you are fulfilling the will of god weather that brings your body or mind some physical or spiritual benefit, or not. 
Rab Elchanan Waserman writes about two aspects in one of his responses in Kovetz Hearot in the section of באורי אגאדות על דרך הפשט . 
Rambam writes specially about that second aspects in Peirush Hamishnayot in Berachot (don't remember exactly where).
So, although is better to know the reasons , we don't need them to fulfill the commandments.

Answer (score 1):

Rambam acknowledges that his reasons for mitzvot might be against the accepted halacha, and he notes that his purpose was not to give reasons according to accepted halacha, but to give reasons based on the Biblical text:

**Guide for the Perplexed 3:41**

> And he who mutilated a limb of his neighbour, must himself lose a
>   limb. "As he hath caused a blemish in a man, so shall it be done to
>   him again" (Lev. xxiv. 20). You must not raise an objection from our
>   practice of imposing a fine in such cases. For we have proposed to
>   ourselves to give here the reason for the precepts mentioned in the
>   Law, and not for that which is stated in the Talmud. I have, however,
>   an explanation for the interpretation given in the Talmud, but it will
>   be communicated *vivâ voce*. ([Friedlander translation](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp177.htm))